# `leafletElement` is getting undefined in react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

When I try the below code-sandbox link in my project. I'm facing issue like leafletElement is getting undefined.

Below are the versions :-

"react-leaflet": "^3.1.0",
"react-leaflet-enhanced-marker": "^1.0.21",

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-kepler-9sw2n?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You are using react-leaflet 2.7 version not 3.1

Comment: @kboul In the above sandbox link it was 2.7 version. But ,when I try to use the latest version i.e  3.1 I'm facing ` leafletElement ` is undefined. can you please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs several adjustments:

1. now zoom and center are immutable meaning you cannot change them via setState. You need to hold the mapReference as state variable to achive that.
2. leafletElement is deprecated when deriving the marker reference
3. openPopup does not expect any args. This comes from the leaflet API and not from react-leaflet

Your code should look like this:

```
    this.state = {
         ...
          map: null,
          marker: null
        };

    openPopUp = (marker, id) => {
        console.log(marker);
        if (marker) marker.openPopup();
      };
    
      clickAction = (id, lat, lng) => {
        if (!this.state.map) return;
        this.state.map.setView([lat, lng], 16);
        this.markerRefs[id].openPopup();
      };
    
      render() {
        return (
          <>
            <MapContainer
              center={center}
              zoom={zoom}
              whenCreated={(map) => this.setState({ map })}
            >
           ...
        )
      }
 }
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/leafletelement-is-getting-undefined-in-react-leaflet-v-3-x-ieeens?file=/src/App.js:448-741)

Comment: Solved the issue.